# DataGrid that masks columns

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpfdatagrid, infragistics, xamdatagrid

Can a `DataGrid` dynamically mask the columns to be displayed?

### Current Setup

`DataGrid` **<--Binding-->** `Collection<Customer>`

1. The type `Customer` has about 100 different fields defined.
2. Different views need to display different sets of columns (about 20 out of 100), chosen somehow dynamically, of the same `Collection<Customer>`.

Is there an option to dynamically mask the fields that will be displayed as columns in the `DataGrid`? Ideally, I want to use Infragistics' `xamDataGrid`, but any solution for a `DataGrid` will be a good starting point.

---

There are other similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5784440/640378) out there, but they deal with either column filtering or variable number of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are defining different views in code you could create different FieldLayouts and use the FieldLayout for the view that is needed.  This would require setting the FieldLayout to be used in code by adding the layout to be used to the FieldLayouts collection.

If you are allowing the end user to define what is in the view, then you will likely want to define all possible fields and then allow the fields to be hidden or shown with the [Field Chooser](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WPF/Current/CLR4.0/?page=xamDataPresenter_Field_Chooser.html).

There are methods for [saving](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WPF/Current/CLR4.0/?page=xamDataPresenter_Save_Field_Customizations.html) and [loading](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WPF/Current/CLR4.0/?page=xamDataPresenter_Load_Field_Customizations.html) customizations to the fields that you can use to persist the layouts.

Comment: looks like I have to write code in the _code-behind_ to initialize the `FieldLayouts`.

Is there a way to do it _MVVM_ styled?

There's a similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3426348/640378) I found which uses _indexers_. Haven't been able to go through it in detail as _indexers_ seem new to me. Just wondering if you think `FieldLayouts` can be initialized in the _MVVM_ style...

Comment: If you are dynamically creating the field layout yourself without auto generating the fields then this will need to be done in c#/vb code and not xaml.